# Sharepoint 2010 2 columns showing up in list from a content type

Tags: 2010

I have a content type with about 20 fields

Everything was fine until I added a hyperlink field called "MySite". When I get to the list instance and add a new item -> low and behold there are 2 "MySite" hyperlink fields instead of just one.

I'm using a content type ref in the list schema not manually adding columns.

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its one of those strange bugs I couldn't find a scientific fix for.

Just redeployed the solution a few times and retracted it, after about 3 attempts without changing code it fixed itself.